# Parametrized login to Database don't work

Tags: c#, sql, authentication

This is the first time I work with Object Oriented C# to Database so I am trying to make an login for my CRM-system with parameterized SQL-Query. The query check if the both the textboxes 'Username' and 'Password' match any records in the database and if it do, it fills an DataTable just for test purpose to see if anythings happens but nothings happens, the Da is empty all the time.

1. Here the code that should send text from textboxes to the parameterized query and then to the "Query Execution Method"

   ```
   private void bLoggaIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string sql = "SELECT * FROM Anvandare WHERE anvandarnamn = @anvandarnamn AND losenord = @losenord";

       SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql);

       sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anvandarnamn", tbAnvandarnamn.Text.Trim().ToString());
       sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@losenord", tbLosenord.Text.Trim().ToString());

       clsDB.ReadFromDatabase(sqlCmd);
   }
   ```
2. This is the method that should execute the query against the database and then return 0 if there is no match or 1 if there is a match but for now, it just fills a `DataTable` with the matched record, just for test purpose but it don't work, the `DataTable` is always empty which means it didn't find any match.

   ```
   public static void ReadFromDatabase(SqlCommand sqlCmd)
   {
       try
       {
           if (!(anslutning.State == ConnectionState.Open)) 
               anslutning.Open();

           sqlCmd.Connection = anslutning;

           SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
           sqlDa.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;

           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           sqlDa.Fill(dt);

           anslutning.Close();
       }
       catch (SqlException undantag)
       {
           string felmeddelande = undantag.Message;
       }
   }
   ```

So why does it not work? I don't understand it should work or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you realy want to use the textbox `tbLosenord` twice?

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anvandarnamn", tbLosenord.Text.Trim().ToString());
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@losenord", tbLosenord.Text.Trim().ToString());
```

For such problems I set a break point (click on the left side of your code editor window in Visual Studio) and use the debugger. The MSDN has many [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx) on the debugger and you can find videos on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEJ5xKO7c3o) to explain it in a more beginner friendly way.